# Bootstrap delete table row

Tags: jquery, row

I was really struggling for days because I did not know how to use the bootstrap delete icon. I found a really really good example that is really similar to my project but it is not quite working.

I love how the existing rows delete, but the newly added rows are NOT deleting! WHY!

Can someone fix this code please?
Really need help

jsfiddle.net/od3n/j24e6ggw/

Comment: "the existing rows delete, but the newly added rows are NOT deleting!". Without checking the fiddle, the answer seems be "event delegation".

Comment: Hey Vohuman, thanks for the fast reply but DOES NOT WORK :(

Comment: You are welcome. What exactly "DOES NOT WORK" mean? Have you read the linked question's answers? How about [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bfb88oro/)? Does this work?

Comment: wow....... I LOVE YOU SO MUCH!!!!! NOW it WORKSS!!! YAYYYY

Comment: I'm glad the fiddle was helpful :) You can read about event delegation [here](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)